# Find two zeros of a function with Python

Tags: python, numpy, math, optimization, scipy

I have a function f(x) which I know has two zeros within an interval and I need to compute both x values for which the function cross 0.

I usually use

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
opt.brentq(f, xmin, xmax)
```

But the problem is this method is working if the function has one 0 in the interval, and it is not very simple to know where to divide in two parts.

The function is also time costly to evaluate...

Comment: Is it a continuous function?

Comment: Does the function have a unique minimum / maximum in the interior of the interval? If so, you could first find the location of that extreme value, for example via [golden section search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search), and then use that to partition your interval into two pieces, each containing one root.

Comment: Shorter version of the above two comments: please give us more information about your function. How do you know it has exactly two zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good approach would be to pre-process the search of the zeros by sampling f before searching for the zeros. During that pre-process, you evaluate f to detect if the sign of the function has changed.

```
def preprocess(f,xmin,xmax,step):
    first_sign = f(xmin) > 0 # True if f(xmin) > 0, otherwise False
    x = xmin + step
    while x <= xmax: # This loop detects when the function changes its sign
        fstep = f(x)
        if first_sign and fstep < 0:
            return x
        elif not(first_sign) and fstep > 0:
            return x
        x += step
    return x # If you ever reach here, that means that there isn't a zero in the function !!!
```

With this function , you can separate your initial interval in several smaller intervals. For example :

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
step = ...
xmid = preprocess(f,xmin,max,step)

z0 = opt.brentq(f,xmin,xmid)
z1 = opt.brentq(f,xmid,xmax)
```

Depending of the functions `f` you use, you may need to separate your interval in more than two sub-intervals. Just iterates through [xmin,xmax] like this :

```
x_list = []
x = x_min
while x < xmax: # This discovers when f changes its sign
    x_list.append(x)
    x = preprocess(f,x,xmax,step)
x_list.append(xmax)

z_list = []
for i in range(len(x_list) - 1):
     z_list.append(opt.brentq(f,x_list[i],x_list[i + 1]))
```

In the end, `z_list` contains all the zeros in the given interval [xmin,xmax].
Keep in mind that this algorithm is time-consuming but will do the job.